# jQuery Mobile selection of radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two rows of radio buttons and depending on the selection, there are invalid combinations. Valid combinations are (bar, year) (bar, state) (area, year) and (map, state). When the user selects 'Area', I want to auto select 'Year' and disable the 'State' radio button. I want to do the same for 'Map' and disable 'Year'. The code that I have should do this, but the selection of the radio button doesn't work. Why not?

Here is the [documentation](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/radiobuttons/methods.html) for the radio buttons.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj8hnkmh/).

```js
$(document).on("change", ".chart-type", function(event, ui) {
    if (this.value == "map") {
        $("#radio-group-by-state").checkboxradio('enable').checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-state").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-year").checkboxradio('disable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    } else if (this.value == "area") {
        $("#radio-group-by-year").checkboxradio('enable').checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-year").attr("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-state").checkboxradio('disable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    } else {
        $("#radio-group-by-state").checkboxradio('enable').checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-year").checkboxradio('enable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain">
    <fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
        <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
            <div class="ui-radio">
                <label data-form="ui-btn-up-a" for="radio-chart-type-bar" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-radio-off ui-first-child">
                    Bar
                </label>
                <input type="radio" value="bar" id="radio-chart-type-bar" class="update-chart chart-type" name="radio-chart-type" data-theme="a">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-radio chart-type-area">
                <label data-form="ui-btn-up-a" for="radio-chart-type-area" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-radio-off">
                    Area
                </label>
                <input type="radio" value="area" id="radio-chart-type-area" class="update-chart chart-type" name="radio-chart-type" data-theme="a">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-radio">
                <label data-form="ui-btn-up-a" for="radio-chart-type-map" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-radio-off ui-last-child">
                    Map
                </label>
                <input type="radio" value="map" id="radio-chart-type-map" class="update-chart chart-type" name="radio-chart-type" data-theme="a">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain">
    <fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
        <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
            <div class="ui-radio">
                <label data-form="ui-btn-up-b" for="radio-group-by-year" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-radio-on ui-btn-active ui-first-child">
                    Year
                </label>
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="year" id="radio-group-by-year" class="update-chart radio-group-by" name="radio-group-by" data-theme="a">
            </div>
            <div class="ui-radio">
                <label data-form="ui-btn-up-b" for="radio-group-by-state" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-radio-off ui-last-child">
                    State
                </label>
                <input type="radio" value="state" id="radio-group-by-state" class="update-chart radio-group-by" name="radio-group-by" data-theme="a">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, enable both checkboxes first, then test for map or area:

```
$(document).on("change", ".chart-type", function(event, ui) {
    $("#radio-group-by-state").checkboxradio('enable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    $("#radio-group-by-year").checkboxradio('enable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    if (this.value == "map") {
        $("#radio-group-by-state").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-year").checkboxradio('disable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    } else if (this.value == "area") {
        $("#radio-group-by-year").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        $("#radio-group-by-state").checkboxradio('disable').checkboxradio("refresh");
    }
});
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jj8hnkmh/1/)**

Comment: That wasn't the issue. For some reason using the `.attr()` function didn't work but your solution used `.prop('checked')` and that was the issue.